# WebBrowser Control does not open

Tags: c#, browser, webbrowser-control

when my event fires the following code get's run:

```
            WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
        browser.Size = new Size(500, 500);
        browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        if (supportingInfo != null)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(supportingInfo.Summary))
                {
                    browser.Navigate("about:blank");
                    if (browser.Document != null)
                    {
                        browser.Document.Write(string.Empty);
                    }
                    browser.DocumentText = "<html>" + supportingInfo.Summary + "</html>";

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

I've debugged and every line of this get's run, but no new browser window opens with my dynamic html. What am I missing to make the window open with my html in it?

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Why should it open new Window?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add the `WebBrowser` control you just created to the form/panel you want it to dock on.  e.g.

```
  this.Controls.Add(browser);
```

You're just creating an instance of the browser and settings it's properties.  No where have you actually added it visually.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I added the control directly to my form, and ran the same code (minus creating the WebBrowser instance) and it ran perfectly. Thank you very much for the prompt reply!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing `browser.Show()`

Comment: `Show` won't do anything until the controls been added.

Comment: Show will open it in a new window, which is what I assumed he wanted since he mentioned no **new** window opened.

Comment: I had tried browser.Show() but that did not resolve it in my case.